# Codeigniter - how to share variables in 2 views from one contoller

Tags: codeigniter, variables, model-view-controller, view

I am using one controller to load 2 views. ViewA - has client credentials, View B has the rest of the webpage (that needs the credentials for further functions)

It looks like any php variables that i load in ViewA are not accessible by viewB. I am open to options on the best and secure way to handle this. Any help is appreciated :)

```
public function tickets($info,  $otherdetails){

    if (file_exists("application/views/accounts/".$info.".php")) {

        $this->load->view('accounts/'.$info);          
        $this->load->view('gui', $data);

    } else {

        show_404();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you invoke this controller method in your route?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
public function tickets($info, $otherdetails)
{
    if (file_exists(VIEWPATH . 'accounts/' . $info . '.php'))
    {
        $this->load->vars($otherdetails);//accessible to all views now
        $this->load->view('accounts/'.$info);
        $this->load->view('gui');

    }
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

[Docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars).